# Two hard drives with separate grub bootloaders

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have two hard drives A and B. On A, I am dual booting linux and windows. On the B, I am trying to install ubuntu server so I can attach the drive to a headless server.

The problem I am encountering is that after I installed ubuntu on B, grub was not starting. I ran a repair tool and now I can boot from B (selected via BIOS) too, however now the grub menu for both A and B are showing each others OS. So both A's and B's grub menu is

```
Boot Linux from A
Boot Windows from A
Boot Linux from B
```

If I try to change the grub menu in A it affects the grub menu when booting from hard drive B too. If I unplug A and boot from B, grub goes into recovery mode.

How can I unlink them so when I boot from A, I only see Linux and Windows from A, and when I boot from B, I only see Linux from B?

Answer (score 1):

If You are able to disconnect power from the hard drives.

Disconnect power from B and reinstall Grub on A.

If all goes well, disconnect power from A and reinstall Grub on B.

When you boot from A, You only see Linux and Windows from A, and when You boot from B, You only see Linux from B.

Whenever any system updates Grub, you must repeat the procedure.

Comment: I already did that and it is not a solution but a hack.